# Make Minimized Forms Visible in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I hope someone can help me out with this.

I am using Access 2016 and I have a main form called frmMainMenu and two other forms called frmAddrecords and frmReports.  I want to be able to minimize frmAddRecords and frmReports but have them still be visible in the lower left corner of frmMainMenu, much the way the windows in the VBA code editor window work.  Right now, when I minimize them, they are only visible in the lower left corner of the desktop so I have to minimize frmMainMenu as well in order to maximize them.  I know in much earlier versions of Access this was possible because I have used programs made with Access that worked this way.

I have tried all of the form settings that seem to be relevant to this issue but haven't had any luck.

I am using Windows 8.1 if that makes a difference.

Thanks,

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Change the form's property *Popup* to False - though that will have other impacts as well.